# cast an array to an array of custom data type

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and so far, its been a tough ride. I might be misunderstanding somethings but here it is. I have the following two interfaces:

```
internal class PersonAttributes
{
    public int SID;
    public int isCurrent;
}

internal class SavedPeople
{
    public int? maxAllowed;
    public PersonAttributes[] people;
}
```

`SavedPeople` is the object that will be returned at last and the people attribute is an array of people with SID and `isCurrent` field for each person. Now i have the following piece of code:

```
            var people = new SavedPeople();
            var currentPeople = JObject.Parse(foundPeople);
            people.maxAllowed = (int)currentPeople["maxAllowed"];
            settings.people = currentPeople["people"].ToArray<PersonAttributes>();
```

`currentPeople` is an object that contains people and `maxAllowed` field. the "people" field is guranteed to contain the same fields as `PersonAttributes`. I want to cast its contents to `PersonAttributes` so when I loop `settings.people`, I get its properties right to set some conditions. The above fails with the following error:

> 'JToken' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToArray' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can you just deserialise the json to the concrete type?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SavedPeople>(foundPeople);
```

2. Use `ToObject<List<T>>()`

```
j["people"].ToObject<List<PersonAttributes>>();
```

BTW. If you want to parse arrays directly use [JArray.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonArray.htm).